# How can one get sound louder for a laptop that comes with Dolby Home Theater?

Tags: sound

Is there anyway to get sound louder if you fail to enable the Dolby Home Theater on Ubuntu? The laptop in question is a Z580 Lenovo. It had good sound under Windows, but in Ubuntu the sound is extremely soft. My guess is that the sound is so soft, because the sound system requires special drivers.

There is a [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/111920/68420) for which the answer suggests installing pulse audio:

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

On running it and going to configuration, there is actually an option for Digital Surround Sound 5.1, but selecting it, just kills the sound completely.

Alternatively, how do you boost your sound power above 100% using the keyboard or default volume control? Using the Pulse Audio Volume control, I am able to push the sound past 100% which does sound much better, but I am unable to do that using the standard volume control on the desktop or using the volume up- and down keys.

Comment: Cool, your post is [linked on github](https://github.com/leoluk/thinkpad-stuff/wiki/Haswell-ThinkPad-problems#linux-low-audio-quality). Have you try contacting Lenovo about it? Remember: manufacturer needs you, needs your feedback, your opinion about any problem you'd meet, even if you're sure that they either know the problem, or/and wouldn't give a solution right away.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [alsamixer](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Audio/Alsamixer)? Please check whether every setting is proper, using that. Use command **`alsamixer`**.

Answer (score 0):

If you have vlc media player installed you can use the settings there to change the sound to fit your system.

VLC can be used for most types of media online or off line,just click on tools in vlc and you can change everything you want to fit your system.

dolby is not (yet)licenced to ubuntu so we have to find other solutions to this.

Answer (score 0):

Edit /home/username/.config/pulse/daemon.conf
Change these line to; (remember to create backup in case things go wrong)

```
default-sample-channels = 6
default-channel-map =front-left,front-right,rear-left,rear-right,front-center,lfe
```

reboot

[Reference](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples)