# How to identify correct pin assignment for HDAJackRetask?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, speakers, hda-intel

I am running 16.04LTS with a multi-speaker enabled laptop (4.1 surround). I am trying to get the audio working on all the four internal speakers. The default audio management package `alsa-mixer` is supposed to detect all the speakers and the subwoofer correctly, but it is not. Only the subwoofer is working and it is getting mapped to the `Front Right` in `Sound Settings > Output > Test Sound`.

[image: Image : Only two speakers detected]

Also, in `alsa-mixer` there should have been more columns (for more speakers), but I only see few.

[image: Image : Few columns in <code>alsa-mixer</code>]

I read a bit and found that the audio pins are not getting retasked properly, and this is already a bug ([Bug report : Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1672822)), and using `HDAJackRetask` it is possible to retask all the pins manually to the respective speakers. I found a post using the same audio codec as mine (Realtek ALC255, [Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/858511/sound-only-through-subwoofer-on-laptop-acer-predator-g9-792)) which makes the real speakers and the subwoofer work correctly, however the front speakers are still don't work. 
Here is a screenshot of all the configurations available in `HDAJackRetask` on my machine :

[image: Part I]

[image: Part II]

I don't know anything about audio hardware, channels or pins. I would be grateful if somebody can help me find the right configuration for all the four speakers. Please let me know if there is a duplicate post anywhere, because I looked a lot and couldn't find it.

Thanks in advance!